# Error executing a project with Google Play Services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I want to create a project that uses "Google Cloud Messaging" and for that I have to import the library "google-play-services-lib". 
I have no problem to import, but when I run the application on my device, Eclipse stops without executing the project. 
If I run the project without the library "google play services" works without problem.
What problem can I have?

EDIT: I solved the problem using a other Eclipse version.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your logcat?

Comment: I can't see the logcat because the Eclipse stops and then not responding. But it only happens when I add to the proyect the library "google-play-services_lib"